# correct way for Zero padding

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency-domain, zero-padding

I am doing simulation of FMCW radar. I am applying signal processing chain on raw radar data. Here in the code below, I am taking `fft` of data and plotting it. Moreover, I am doing zero padding by multiplying the signal length by 1000. I should be getting beat frequency at 2.020 MHz instead I am getting at 2.019MHz. There is something little probelem but I do not know what.

Is it the correct way for Zero padding? Moreover, am I defining frequency axes correctly? Thanks everyone in advance

```
% second-order butterworth
[b, a] = butter(2, [w1 w2], 'bandpass');


load('fb2030');                                   % loading the data
x = fb2030(30,:);
% filtering
y_filt = filter(b,a,x);                           % filtering the received signal
nfft = length(y_filt)*1000;                       %%%% Zero Padding
res = fft(y_filt,nfft)/ nfft;                     % normalizing the fft


f = fs/2*linspace(0,1,nfft/2+1);                  % choosing correct frequency axes
res = res(1:nfft/2+1);                            % amplitude of fft(taking the half length of nfft)
figure,plot(f,2*abs(res));
xlabel('Frequency in MHz');ylabel('amp')
```

Comment: Nothing looks obviously wrong. You should elaborate on "not getting the desired output."

Comment: Thanks Jason for your answer. I mean, I am applying fft on radar data. At the end, I shoud be getting beat frequency at 2.020MHz instead I am getting at 2.019MHz. Therefore, i am thinking that may be I am applying zero padding wrong or defining wrong frequency axes.

Comment: @Urban_Yogi I think you should include this info into your question. This will help giving a better answer to your question.

Comment: Done @ Gilles. Thansk for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This line seems suspicious to me:

```
f = fs/2*linspace(0,1,nfft/2+1);
```

Your frequency bins should be:

$$f_k = \frac{f_s}{\tt nfft} k$$

so

$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
f_{{\tt nfft}/2 + 1} &=& \frac{f_s}{\tt nfft} ({\tt nfft}/2 + 1)\\
&=& \frac{f_s}{2} + \frac{f_s}{\tt nfft} 
\end{array}$$

whereas your `linspace` setting has it mapping to just $\frac{f_s}{2}$.

Comment: Or you meant $f_{{\tt nfft}/2 + 1} = \frac{f_s}{2} + \frac{f_s}{\tt nfft}$ ? And I think the choice of `linspace` is on purpose so as to only have a single side amplitude spectrum.

Comment: ahh ok. let me try. Thanks for your answer Peter K.

Comment: @Gilles: Yes, I have corrected my typo.  Linspace is OK, but the range is wrong.  And the range being wrong will mean the frequencies being plotted are wrong.

Comment: @PeterK. The remaining range from $\frac{f_s}{2}$ to $f_s$ is an image of what is already from $0$ to $\frac{f_s}{2}$. I don't think this will help solve his problem.

Comment: That's the trouble:  He's NOT doing 0 to $f_s/2$.  He's doing 0 to $f_s/2 + f_s/{\tt nfft}$. So he's including part of the range from $f_s/2$ to $f_s$ in what he thinks is 0 to $f_s/2$.